# Cypher query to find nodes with shared properties, and formulate as input and output

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have searched to find a way to query my data in order to build a table to visualize it properly. The data is an import of a SysML model. The general structure of the data is this:

```
(node1:Type1)<-[:Reference]-(node2:Type1)-[:Property]->(node3:Type1)<-[:Property]-(node4:Type1)-[:Reference]->(node5:Type1)
```

Nodes **2 and 4** represent processes, with data being exchanged between them. The data exchanged is represented by **node 3**. Nodes **1 and 5**, represent the tools in which these processes are performed. My ideal situation would be to have a table with columns

```
 node1.name | node2.name | node3.name | node4.name | node5.name
```

allowing me to view the inputs/outputs of my processes and which tools perform those processes, effectively evaluating the interfaces. However, the queries I'm using are causing duplicates in the rows of the tables, as it's reading 'front to back' as well as 'back to front'. Is there a way to separate each 'step' of the path, and make a column for each step (perhaps by relationship direction)? There are also cases where there is more than one "tool" `(node 1 or 5)` in which these processes are performed, so a row for each (many to one, one to one, one to many, many to many) would be ideal. Lastly, there are cases where a process `(nodes 2 and 4)` may have more than just a single relationship. I would like to be able to show all of the process interfaces.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the mirrored results issue, it helps to use an inequality predicate on the ids of the nodes to ensure a single result: `WHERE id(node1) < id(node5)`

As for showing all possible paths, that's what Cypher does, so you should see all possible paths that fit the pattern.

Comment: OK, great, this seemed to work. I added the inequality between nodes 2 & 4 as those are really the defining features of the relationship, which got rid of the mirror. Thank you very much for you help.